# how to make custom carousal in react material ui?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

i already made a carousal but its taking images to next row.i want all images in one line.
here is codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-bouman-kyle9y?file=/src/Carousal.js

Comment: Does this help? https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-cori-qt5usf?file=/src/Carousal.js

Comment: no.because next and previous button is not working. Can u fix this?

Comment: before prev next button was working. The issue was pics was coming to next row.